# Check if specific external disk is connected

Tags: command-line, external-hdd

How can I check via shell command if a specific external disk is connected? (by label or device id)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To test whether a specific device is connected you can use `grep` with the `-q` option to search the output of `lsusb` or `lsblk`, e.g.

```bsh
uuid=f9035fce-b3a1-4aee-80ef-44e432b78fdb
lsblk -f | grep -wq $uuid && echo yes || echo no

devicename="some Inc. Keyboard"
lsusb | grep -q "$devicename" && echo yes || echo no
```

or with `if`:

```bsh
uuid=f9035fce-b3a1-4aee-80ef-44e432b78fdb
if lsblk -f | grep -wq $uuid; then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

Both can be used no matter whether the device is mounted.

Comment: For mounted partitions - `lsblk -f | grep f9035fce-b3a1-4aee-80ef-44e432b78fdb | grep / -q  && echo yes || echo no` .

Comment: Of course, I used UUID which you provided :)

Answer (score 10):

`/dev/disk/` contains the following directories, which contain symbolic link to real devices. This links are dynamically created and removed by `udev`, so they're a are always up-to-date:

- by-id
- by-partlabel
- by-partuuid
- by-path
- by-uuid

So checking for the existence of the symlink will use less resources.

Here is an example testing the presence of a disk using its serial number:

```
test -e /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5002538d408be9e0 && echo yes || echo no
```

In my backup script I even don't check the disk presence, I only check the result of the `mount` command like this:

```
mount -o noatime $DESTINATION_PARTITION $DESTINATION_DIR || exit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`lsusb` for listing connected usb device if your external disk is connected through USB interface.

`lsblk -f` to list block devices, UUIDs and their mount-points as your external disk is a block device.

Comment: @N0rbert why do you need `-f` to list mount points? The default output lists them anyway

Answer (score 0):

`findfs` is made for this.  You can search by :

- FS label

  ```
  findfs LABEL="Ubuntu" &>/dev/null
  ```
- FS uuid

  ```
  findfs UUID="f9035fce-b3a1-4aee-80ef-44e432b78fdb" &>/dev/null
  ```
- GPT label

  ```
  findfs PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" &>/dev/null
  ```
- [GPT uuid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121176/259669)

  ```
  findfs PARTUUID="85e66d2f-3709-4060-938e-ffe836433cc9" &>/dev/null
  ```

Searches are case sensitive.  If multiple partitions match, only the last one is displayed.